# Bad return status for 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)

Tags: release-hera, kernel

I have a fresh install of *elementaryos 5.1.7* on *ubuntu 18.04.4* on an otherwise os-less 2008 macbook, and in classic fashion I'm trying to install *bcmwl-kernel-source* to turn on my wifi. I think I've installed all the necessary packages and dependencies with some flash drive hopping, but when I try to dpkg the folder the installation fails and tells me

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
[sudo] password for funandoatmeal:          
(Reading database ... 144607 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9) over (2.3-3ubuntu9) ...
Preparing to unpack dpkg-dev_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) over (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc_7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) over (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc-7_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-7 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc-7-base_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-7-base:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc-8-base_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-8-base:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libasan4_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan4:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libatomic1_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) over (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Preparing to unpack libc6-dev_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) over (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Preparing to unpack libcc1-0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcc1-0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libc-dev-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) over (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Preparing to unpack libcilkrts5_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libdpkg-perl_1.19.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) over (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack libgcc1_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc1:amd64 (1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libgcc-7-dev_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-7-dev:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libitm1_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libitm1:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack liblsan0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblsan0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libmpx2_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpx2:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libquadmath0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libquadmath0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libtsan0_8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtsan0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) over (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack libubsan0_7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libubsan0:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) over (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-122.124_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-122.124) over (4.15.0-122.124) ...
Preparing to unpack make_4.1-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.1-9.1ubuntu1) over (4.1-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gcc-7-base:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up gcc-8-base:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-122.124) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libgcc1:amd64 (1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libmpx2:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libubsan0:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up make (4.1-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.19.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libasan4:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libcc1-0:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up libgcc-7-dev:amd64 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up gcc-7 (7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) ...
Setting up gcc (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.4.0-42-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.4.0-42-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/elementary--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

s

And make.log tells me this

```
DKMS make.log for bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom for kernel 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Fri Oct 30 12:13:42 PDT 2020
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_pci_probe’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:780:2: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  if ((val & 0x0000ff00) != 0)
  ^~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:782:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
   bar1_size = pci_resource_len(pdev, 2);
   ^~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_dev_ioctl’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:462:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_ds’; did you mean ‘get_fs’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  set_fs(get_ds());
         ^~~~~~
         get_fs
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:462:9: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘set_fs’
In file included from ./include/linux/uaccess.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/fpu/xstate.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h:26,
                 from ./include/linux/mm.h:99,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/include/linuxver.h:65,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:26:
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h:29:20: note: expected ‘mm_segment_t {aka struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 static inline void set_fs(mm_segment_t fs)
                    ^~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:40:0:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c: In function ‘wl_set_auth_type’:
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h:52:5: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
  if (wl_dbg_level & WL_DBG_DBG) {   \
     ^
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:816:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘WL_DBG’
   WL_DBG(("network eap\n"));
   ^~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c:817:2: note: here
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:273: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o] Error 1
Makefile:1731: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build' failed
make: *** [/var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic'
```

I don't have much advanced or even intermediate linux knowledge, so I'd appreciate being walked through this some.
Big thanks and apologies

Comment: It's possible that you have got the wrong versions of the packages. The installation media (USB stick you used to install elementary) should have the bcmwl-kernel-source package inside a pool folder. Have you tried installing that one?

Comment: I just connected my computer to my phone and used it to connect to the internet, and updated everything through the terminal. Whoops. All good now. Thanks everyone.